# Stop nginx redirect to proxy_pass location

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have two domains: abc.com and def.com. I am running a Django application behind nginx. Single django application has two apps running under different URL, app1 is running under url: localhost/corp and app2 is running under url: localhost:/service.
Now I want to server /corp on abc.com and /service on def.com domain.
For this I have done this NGINX configuration:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name abc.com;

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/site/site.sock:/corp;
        }
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name def.com;

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/site/site.sock:/service;
        }
}
```

But the configuration is not working this way, when I visit abc.com, I get redirected to abc.com/corp and when visiting def.com, its redirected to def.com/service. Instead, I want /corp content to be served on abc.com root and /service content on def.com root domain itself. How can I modify this configuration to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried adding a trailing `/` to the URIs in the `proxy_pass` statements?